# An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response WCF

Tags: c#, api, http, wcf, binding

I have a Windows app connecting to a WCF service that uses Entity Framework and is hosted in IIS. I get this error message when I try to return result of method in WCF service to my windows app:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost/BuyAndRechargeWcfService/BuyAndRechargeService.svc.   > This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Here is my `web.config` file of the WCF service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
        <add key="DatabaseName" value="Recharge System"/>
        <add key="ServerName" value="SAA"/>
        <add key="UserId" value="sa"/>
        <add key="Password" value="**"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
    <entityFramework>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Here is `exe.config` file in Windows app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="DatabaseName" value="Recharge System"/>
        <add key="ServerName" value="SAA"/>
        <add key="UserId" value="sa"/>
        <add key="Password" value="**"/>
        <add key="DataSourceType" value="wcf"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IBuyAndRechargeService" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost/BuyAndRechargeWcfService/BuyAndRechargeService.svc"
                      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IBuyAndRechargeService"
                      contract="BuyAndRechargeService.IBuyAndRechargeService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IBuyAndRechargeService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
  </startup>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Here is service code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using EntityFarmework;
using Sedco.SelfService.Kiosk.SharedProject;

namespace BuyAndRechargeWcfService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "BuyAndRechargeService" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select BuyAndRechargeService.svc or BuyAndRechargeService.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class BuyAndRechargeService : IBuyAndRechargeService
    {
        private readonly BuyAndRechargeSystemModel _dataBaseEntities = new BuyAndRechargeSystemModel(new DatabaseConfiguration().GetWebConfiguration());
        
        public dynamic HandleCustomer(string action, Dictionary<string, string> customerData)
        {
            dynamic result = null;
            switch (action)
            {
                case "checkExistingPhoneNumber":
                    {
                        result= CheckExistingPhoneNumber(customerData);
                        break;
                    }

                case "getCustomers":
                    {

                        result= GetCustomers();

                        break;
                    }

                case "getCustomerInformation":
                    {
                        result= GetCustomerInformation(customerData);
                        break;
                    }
                case "rechargeBalance":
                    {
                        result= RechargeBalance(customerData);
                        break;
                    }

                case "getFilteredCustomers":
                    {
                        result= GetFilteredCustomers(customerData);
                        break;
                    }
                case "deleteCustomers":
                    {
                        result= DeleteCustomers(customerData);
                        break;
                        
                    }
                case "checkIfNoCustomers":
                    {
                        result= CheckIfNoCustomers();
                        break;
                    }
                case "addCustomer":
                    {
                        result= AddCustomer(customerData);
                        break;
                    }
                case "getExpireDate":
                {
                    result= GetExpireDate(customerData);
                    break;
                }
                case "editCustomer":
                    {
                        result= EditCustomer(customerData);
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    return false;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public dynamic HandlePackages(string action, Dictionary<string, string> packageInfo)
        {
            dynamic result = null;
            switch (action)
            {
                case "getPackagesList":
                    result = _dataBaseEntities.Packages.Where(package => package.Type.Equals(packageInfo["packageType"]))
                        .Select(package => package.Name).ToList();
                    break;
                case "addPackage":
                    try
                    {
                        Packages package = new Packages();
                        package.Name = packageInfo["packageName"];
                        package.Type = packageInfo["packageType"];
                        package.price = Int32.Parse(packageInfo["packagePrice"]);
                        _dataBaseEntities.Packages.Add(package);
                        _dataBaseEntities.SaveChanges();
                        result = true;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        result = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case "getPackageTypeFromName":
                    result = _dataBaseEntities.Packages.Where(package => package.Name.Equals(packageInfo["packageName"]))
                        .Select(package => package.Type).FirstOrDefault();
                    break;
                case "checkExistingPackages":
                    int packages = _dataBaseEntities.Packages.Where(package => package.Name == packageInfo["packageName"])
                        .Select(package => package.Name).Count();
                    result = packages != 0;
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        }

        private bool EditCustomer(Dictionary<string, string> customerData)
        {
            bool isEdited = false;

            Customers customer =
                _dataBaseEntities.Customers.FirstOrDefault(customerPhone =>
                    customerPhone.PhoneNumber.Equals(customerData["phoneNumber"]));
            if (customer != null)
            {
                int packageId = _dataBaseEntities.Packages.Where(package => package.Name.Equals(customerData["packageName"]))
                    .Select(package => package.ID).FirstOrDefault();
                customer.Name = customerData["editCustomerName"];
                customer.BirthDate = customerData["editCustomerBirthDate"];
                customer.PackageID = packageId;
                _dataBaseEntities.SaveChanges();
                isEdited = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isEdited = false;
            }

            return isEdited;
        }

        private DateTime GetExpireDate(Dictionary<string, string> customerData)
        {
            DateTime? expireDate = _dataBaseEntities.Customers
                .Where(customer => customer.PhoneNumber.Equals(customerData["phoneNumber"]))
                .Select(customer => customer.ExpireDate)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            return (DateTime)expireDate;
        }

        private bool AddCustomer(Dictionary<string, string> customerData)
        {
            bool result = false;

            try
            {
                Customers customer = new Customers();
                int packageId = _dataBaseEntities.Packages.Where(package => package.Name.Equals(customerData["packageName"]))
                    .Select(package => package.ID).SingleOrDefault();
                int packagePrice = _dataBaseEntities.Packages.Where(package => package.Name.Equals(customerData["packageName"]))
                    .Select(package => package.price).FirstOrDefault();
                string expireDateADateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                DateTime expireDate = DateTime.ParseExact(expireDateADateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                customer.Name = customerData["customerName"];
                customer.PhoneNumber = customerData["phoneNumber"];
                customer.BirthDate = customerData["customerBirthDate"];
                customer.PackageID = packageId;
                customer.ExpireDate = expireDate;
                customer.Balance = packagePrice;
                _dataBaseEntities.Customers.Add(customer);
                _dataBaseEntities.SaveChanges();
                result = true;
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                e.EntityValidationErrors.SelectMany(error => error.ValidationErrors).ToList().ForEach(
                    item => Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", item.PropertyName, item.ErrorMessage));
                result = false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = false;
            }

            return result;
        }

        private bool CheckIfNoCustomers()
        {
            bool isNoCustomer = false;
            int countOfCustomers = _dataBaseEntities.Customers.Count();
            if (countOfCustomers == 0)
            {
                isNoCustomer = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isNoCustomer = false;
            }

            return isNoCustomer;
        }

        private bool DeleteCustomers(Dictionary<string, string> customerData)
        {
            bool isDeleted = true;
            bool result = false;
            List<Customers> deleteQuery = new List<Customers>();
            foreach (string phoneNumber in customerData["phoneNumber"].Split(','))
            {
                Customers customerRow =
                    _dataBaseEntities.Customers.Single(customer => customer.PhoneNumber.Equals(phoneNumber));
                deleteQuery.Add(customerRow);

                if (customerRow != null)
                {
                    isDeleted = true && isDeleted;
                }
                else
                {
                    isDeleted = false && isDeleted;
                    break;
                }
            }

            foreach (Customers delete in deleteQuery)
            {
                if (isDeleted)
                {
                    _dataBaseEntities.Customers.Remove(delete);
                    _dataBaseEntities.SaveChanges();
                    result = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = false;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        private List<Customer> GetFilteredCustomers(Dictionary<string, string> customerData)
        {
            return _dataBaseEntities.Customers
                .Where(customers =>
                    customers.Name.Contains(customerData["Search"]) ||
                    customers.PhoneNumber.Contains(customerData["Search"])).Select(customer => new Customer
                    {
                        CustomerName = customer.Name,
                        CustomerPhoneNumber = customer.PhoneNumber,
                        CustomerBirthdate = customer.BirthDate,
                        CustomerPackageName = customer.Packages.Name,
                        CustomerBalance = Convert.ToDecimal(customer.Balance)
                    }).ToList();
        }

        private string RechargeBalance(Dictionary<string, string> customerData)
        {
            Customers customerBalance = _dataBaseEntities.Customers.Single(customerPhoneNumber =>
                customerPhoneNumber.PhoneNumber.Equals(customerData["PhoneNumber"]));
            customerBalance.Balance = customerBalance.Balance + Convert.ToDecimal(customerData["Amount"]);
            IFormatProvider culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            customerBalance.ExpireDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                "dd-MM-yyyy", culture);
            _dataBaseEntities.SaveChanges();
            return customerBalance.Balance.ToString();
        }

        private Customer GetCustomerInformation(Dictionary<string, string> customerData)
        {
            return _dataBaseEntities.Customers
                .Where(customers => customers.PhoneNumber.Equals(customerData["PhoneNumber"])).Select(
                    customer => new Customer
                    {
                        CustomerName = customer.Name,
                        CustomerPhoneNumber = customer.PhoneNumber,
                        CustomerBirthdate = customer.BirthDate,
                        CustomerPackageName = customer.Packages.Name,
                        CustomerBalance = (decimal)customer.Balance
                    }).Single();
        }

        private XmlNode[] GetCustomers()
        {
            var customers = _dataBaseEntities.Customers.Select(customerInfo => new Customer
            {
                CustomerName = customerInfo.Name,
                CustomerPhoneNumber = customerInfo.PhoneNumber,
                CustomerBirthdate = customerInfo.BirthDate,
                CustomerPackageName = customerInfo.Packages.Name,
                CustomerBalance = (decimal)customerInfo.Balance
            }).ToList();

            //Convert the List<Customer> object to an XmlNode[] object
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Customer>));
            using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, customers);
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.LoadXml(stringWriter.ToString());
                return xmlDoc.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlNode>().ToArray();
            }
        }

        private bool CheckExistingPhoneNumber(Dictionary<string, string> customerData)
        {
            return _dataBaseEntities.Customers.Count(
                number => number.PhoneNumber == customerData["PhoneNumber"]) != 0;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to debug the code I reach the return value of `HandleCustomer` method in WCF service and then I can't complete debugging (can't move to other statement the arrows is been disabled).

Please tell me if you want to provide you in any other parts of code

Answer (score 0):

If possible, please check whether there is a record of 0 in the data found in the database.

When read in a program, it is converted to the corresponding enumeration type (enum), which does not define the enumeration value corresponding to 0. In this case, the conversion to an enumeration type does not throw an exception, and the value of the property remains 0 after the conversion. But when it is returned to the WCF client, the above exception is thrown.

The solution is to define the enumerated value corresponding to 0 in the enumerated type.